# Compare Number Of Lines In 2 Files and add one line in one of the files

Tags: bash, shell-script

For a validation process, I need to compare the number of lines between two files. I know how to do this (code shown below). However, if the process works as expected, one file will have always one extra line. So, process will be successful if file1 = file2+1. How can I add this extra line in the if command?

```
if [ "$(wc -l < file1.txt)" -eq "$(wc -l < file2.txt)" ]; then echo 'Match!'; else echo 'Warning: No Match!'; fi
```

Comment: Which shell do you use, and what arithmetic does it offer?

Comment: How can I know that?

Comment: E.g., amongst others: 
`echo $SHELL<Ret>
/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your shell is (a recent) `bash` offering "process substitution", and "arithmetic expansion", try

```
{ read LN1 X; read LN2 X; } < <(wc -l file[12]); if (( ! LN2 - LN1 - 1 )); then echo 'match!'; fi
```